# Can a three year famine be dated within the reign of Ahab?

Tags: 1-kings, chronology

Are there any historical writings or any archaeological evidence for a three year famine during the reign of Ahab as mentioned in [1 Kings 18:1](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+kings+18%3A1&version=NET)?

Answer (score 1):

There is evidence external to the Bible that King Ahab existed. The Kurkh Monoliths (pictured below) mention King Ahab and the military assistance he offerd to Shalmaneser III during the [Battle of Qarqar.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Qarqar)

[image: Kurkh Monolith]

To date no archaeological evidence or written references have been found that corroborate the famine mentioned in 1 Kings 18:1. The city of Jezreel is a [semi-active](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jezreel_(city)) dig site however, [with digs periodically](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:kstIbJqtO5YJ:www.biblicalarchaeology.org/daily/archaeology-today/biblical-archaeology-topics/jezreel-expedition-sheds-new-light-on-ahab-and-jezebel%25E2%2580%2599s-city/+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) led by Archeologists David Ussishkin and John Woodhead. As they continue to excavate this site they may find additional evidence of the famine during the reign of King Ahab once they dig down to that time period.

Answer (score 1):

The chronology of the early Hebrew kings received archaeological support when the Kurkh stela found its way to the London museum in 1861.  On the limestone slab, Shalmaneser 3 of Assyria recounted his epic battle with a confederation of kings at Qarqar in 853 BC, and his description included Ahab of Israel, who joined the alliance against him with 2000 chariots and 10,000 soldiers.  So, Ahab was still alive then.

However, it was not until Dr. Edwin Thiele nailed the death of Ahab to later in the same year at the battle of Ramoth-Gilead, that an absolute date in the Hebrew timeline could be identified.   After repulsing the Assyrians, the fragile alliance between Aram and Israel apparently broke into old hostilities. (1 Kings 22) In any case, Thiele proved that **853 BC marked an absolute date**, from which the reigns of other kings could be calculated.

Two earlier battles between Ahab and Ben Hadad 2 are recounted in 1 Kings 20, which were three years earlier than Ramoth-Gilead. (1 Kings 22:1)  Therefore they can be placed in the years **857 and 856 BC.**

Now to the question: The famine isn’t explicitly dated, but it preceded the above mentioned conflict by a seemingly short time.  1 Kings 18:1 reads, “in the third year.”  This was a calendrical expression meaning the third year of the Hebrew heptad of seven – the Sabbath year cycle.  The Sabbath years have been the subject of debate, but if we extrapolate the dates given by Jewish scholar, Benedict Zuckermann, Sabbath years may have occurred in **864 BC and 857 BC.**  If that is the case, the famine would have been in the early half of that period.

My timeline of the [Hebrew kings here](http://5loaves2fishes.net/pdfs/kings.pdf) (click House of Omri)

Comment: The question was if there was "any archaeological evidence for a three year famine". I take it that your answer is "no".

Answer (score 0):

There is no mention of conflict between Israel (Samaria) and Aram (Syria) until Menahem is king of Samaria in the Bible.  Also Ahab fought three battles against Syria.  Why would he align with Syria against Assyria.
The Biblical timeline for the kings of Judah is correct and from it the timeline of the kings of Samaria can be determined.  Therefore the reign of king Ahab was 918-899 BC, meaning he was dead long before the Battle of Qarqar in 853 BC.  See my article in historyfiles below for more detail.

http://www.historyfiles.co.uk/FeaturesMiddEast/CanaanIsraelites_Qarqar01.htm

Comment: Welcome to the site, W.R. Your answer was interesting but did not seem to actually answer the question about a 3-year famine. You gave a link to an article you have written, but if that article actually deals with the famine in question, it would be more helpful for you to copy the relevant bit(s) and put them in your answer. Perhaps you could do that?

Comment: The point is that you have to look at the correct time period to find any evidence of the famine.  Even so it would be almost impossible to find any evidence of a famine that happened nearly 3000 years ago.